# How to access this these two array in $.ajax response?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, each

The first one can be accessed easily like `reponse[0].status == 200` but how can I access the second one

```
0: {status: "200"}
1: {2: "Sector-5[Men]", 3: "Sector-20", 4: "CHM", 5: "Tower Dump", 6: "Kalka", 7: "Pinjore", 8: "CIA-26", 9: "Sector-14", 12: "local Complaint", 13: "CIA-19&Detective Staff", 14: "MDC", 15: "Sector-5[Woman]", 19: "Raipur Rani"}
```

this is the result after json.parse from $.ajax response

My ajax code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: 'toFetchData.php', 
    data: {'for' : 'forRegister'}, 
    success :function(response){ 
        var a = JSON.parse(response); 
        var register = "<option value=''>Select Register Name</option>"; 
        if(a[0].status == '200'){ 
            $.each(a[1], function(key,value){ 
                $.each(value, function(Number,Name){ 
                    console.log(Number+" , "+Name); 
                }); 
            }); 
        } 
    } 
});
```

Comment: first one can be accessed easily like reponse[0].status == 200        but how we can second one ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: The second one what?` Please show the actual object instead of the console.log and tell us what you need and what you tried

Comment: Your second is `reponse[1]`

Comment: yes response[1] is second one but when i'm trying to get key & value by applying $.each(response[0]) it show me [object object] in the place of [key value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `.each()`

Working example:

```js
var a = {1: {2: "Sector-5[Men]", 3: "Sector-20", 4: "CHM", 5: "Tower Dump", 6: "Kalka", 7: "Pinjore", 8: "CIA-26", 9: "Sector-14", 12: "local Complaint", 13: "CIA-19&Detective Staff", 14: "MDC", 15: "Sector-5[Woman]", 19: "Raipur Rani"}};


$.each(a[1],function(key,value){
   console.log(key +' : '+value);
});


/*or you can use like below as well
$.each(a,function(key,value){
  $.each(value,function(k,v){
   console.log(k +' : '+v);
  });
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thnks sir, it's running well now